# Ruby nokogiri LoadError: How to change library search path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, nokogiri, rbenv

When I executed a ruby script, I got the following error. The script uses 'nokogiri'. It seems to search 'libxml2.2.dylib' from '/Users/XXX/.bundler/tmp/...' but the library is actually in '/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.0/lib/libxml2.2.dylib'.

The searched directory (/Users/XXX/.bundler/tmp/10029/) does not exist.

```
ruby test.rb

/Users/XXX/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': dlopen(/Users/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392
/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /Users/XXX/.bundler/tmp/10029/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-d
arwin11/libxml2/2.8.0/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
  Reason: Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0 - /Users/yus
aku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
```

How can I change the library search path?

I followed the official installation of 'Nokogiri' (home-brew 0.9)
http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt
brew link libxml2 libxslt

wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
cd libiconv-1.13.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1
make
sudo make install

gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.0/include/libxml2/ 
                        --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.0/lib 
                        --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 
                        --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include 
                        --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

Any suggestion or at least direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Problem solved for the time being. 1. reinstall rbenv 2. install ruby and nokogiri by using Macports. Sorry I posted the terrible question.